Generators of positive quantum evolution
It is known that a generator of completely positive evolution, a Lindbladian $\mathcal{L}$, can always be represented in the following form:
\begin{equation*}
   \mathcal{L}(\rho) = -i [H,\rho] + \Phi(\rho) - \frac{1}{2} \{ \Phi^{\dagger}, \rho \},  
\end{equation*}
where $ \Phi$ is a completely positive (CP) map; see, e.g., notes by M. Wolf [1]. The representation is not unique, of course.
My question is about a construction of generators $\mathcal{L}_p$ of positive evolution (not necessarily completely positive).
Specifically, can I assume (i)  that such a generator can be obtained by replacing the original CP map $ \Phi $ with a positive (P) map $ \Psi $?
Next,  (ii) is it correct to say that a generator of positive evolution can always be represented in a form similar to the one above, if I replace the original CP map $ \Phi $ with a positive (P) map $ \Psi $?
[1] https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1701036/document.pdf

In general, checking positivity (rather than CP-ness) of maps is a hard problem; one way to see this is that it is equivalent to checking for entanglement (which is known to be NP-hard).

@ NorbertSchuch Thank you for the comment. But , I think, my problem  is simpler (sorry for not making it clear): How to construct it in a way that positivity is guaranteed. Everything is under the control and all can be chosen/constructed  as needed.

Well, the second part of your question (last paragraph) is pretty much exactly that (unless you only care about constructing a subclass). Maybe you should focus on one question. (For the subclass, there is the notion of decomposible witnesses (=positive maps), which can be written as the sum of a state and its partial transpose, IIRC. But they are only a subclass.)

@NorbertSchuch You are indeed correct about my last paragraph. Let's drop it now and keep only the first part. Namely, can I, once given a P map $\Psi$, construct a generator of P evolution as described by the expression in the question?

This is not what your question is asking. Your question is asking the opposite!

Thank you again. I amended the question(s). Could you now please address  them? Or just one of them, that would be great.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
